# Ensure that all 2**N combinations are generated in M random outputs of N booleans

Tags: python, numpy, random

In this example below M = 10 and N = 2, and since M is considerably larger than 2**N, the probability is that every possible combination of N booleans, (True, True), (True False), (False, True), (False, False) in this example, will be generated among the M outputs at least once, as has occurred below.

```
for _ in range(10):
...     choice1 = np.random.choice((True, False))
...     choice2 = np.random.choice((True, False))
...     print(choice1, choice2)
...     
False False
False False
True False
True False
True True
False True
True True
True True
True False
False False
```

But it isn't guaranteed. There is a low probability of getting 10 X (False, False) or alternatively 10 X (True, True), or perhaps a mix where one particular pair, say (False, True), never appears.

In 'real life' the print is replaced by a yield statement, and `choice1` and `choice2` are accompanied by several other randomly generated numeric variables.

How could I easily change the generation of `choice1` and `choice2` to make sure they always cover all of the 4 possibilities, while still keeping it (mostly) random, without just adding 4 extra non-random cases to force them to occur?

I feel as if the selection without replacement option could be exploited, but I can't think how to incorporate this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure that each possible combination is used at leat once you can first create a list with all the possible combinations then randomly pop (pick and remove) an element. When your list is empty you recreate it.

The drawback is that you cant get the same element twice before all the elements where popped.

The following code seems to do the job:

```py
import random
import copy
from itertools import product 
M = 10
N = 2

#fist generate all the possible combinations:
all_combinations_ref = product([True,False],repeat =N)
all_combinations = list(copy.copy(all_combinations_ref))
#now randomly pop one element:
for i in range(M):
    if len(all_combinations) == 0:
        all_combinations = list(copy.copy(all_combinations_ref))
    print(all_combinations.pop(random.randint(0,len(all_combinations)-1)))
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

This answer does exactly what I want. It does not have the drawback of the one from R Liab, although that was helpful - thanks - in deriving this one.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

N = 2
M = 10
possibles = product((True, False), repeat=N)

selection_pool = list(possibles)
not_yet_used = set(selection_pool)
m2go = M

while m2go > 0:
    if m2go <= len(not_yet_used):
        selection_pool = list(not_yet_used)
    used = selection_pool[np.random.choice(len(selection_pool))]
    not_yet_used.discard(used)
    print(*used)
    m2go -= 1
```